# Add CSRF token to cookie, python cgi

Tags: python, apache, cookies, cgi

Apache modsecurity is warning of missing CSRF tokens on requests for web pages on my demo (Ubuntu) server. 
The local time and the cookie string on a python cgi form print on submit as:
local time: 2013-11-07 12:56:13 cookie: 40-character-sequence
(The cookie changes on each submit action.) How do I add a token to the cookie to meet modsecurity standards?

Comment: consider _not_ using CGI, and instead using a small framework that has some builtin support for this, like Flask with `flask-csrf`.

Comment: I'm looking to upload this script on to a web hosting service, to be linked from a joomla website.  The service offers python (and perl and ruby) cgi, but I won't have the freedom to install another framework on the remote host.  The CSRF errors that appear in my demo server's apache logs may not be a problem for them but I'd appreciate your feedback.

Comment: depends entirely how your host is set up, of course, but you can install python libraries locally with `pip install --user`